# How to perform Breusch pagan-test for lmList object in r?

Tags: r, list, lm

I am doing multiple regressions on one data frame using lmList from the lme4 packade.
On each of the regressions, I want to do a test of heteroskedasticity.
Have tried the Breusch pagan-test without sucess. This is the example data:

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(group=c(rep("a",10), rep("b",10), rep("c",10)), 
                   x=rnorm(30), y1=rnorm(30), y2=rnorm(30), y3=rnorm(30))

regs <- lmList(cbind(y1, y2, y3) ~ x | group, dat)
```

Resulting in nine regressions.
My attempt so far (using the "lmtest"-package) is:

```
library(lmtest)

lapply(regs, bptest)
```

however, that only performs the test divided on a,b and c, not on each y1, y2 and y3 within these. So three tests instead of nine. Also tried to "reach" within group a to make the three tests for that group:

```
asum <- summary(regs$a)
bptest(asum$`Response y1`)
```

leading to an error message "Error in model.matrix.default(terms(formula), model.frame(formula)) :
model frame and formula mismatch in model.matrix()".

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `lmtest::bptest` does not support multiple LHS formulas.  Consider reporting that to the maintainer of that package, `maintainer("lmtest")`

In the meantime, to work around that use (3) in [How to make regression based on grouped rows and loop over columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107894/how-to-make-regression-based-on-grouped-rows-and-loop-over-columns/66108177#66108177)